# Using Git to manage a file with different content for each branch and merging

Tags: git

I have a app.yaml and php.ini file that has a different set of configurations for staging and production.

I want to create 3 separate branches. 1) Local, 2) Staging, 3) production.

The problem is that if I branch and create different files for each environment one settings will be overwritten by the other when I perform a merge. For example, when I merge my staging branch into production the config file will now contain staging settings and will not work in the production environment.

How do I get around this issue while keeping track of the changes of each file in individual branches through git. I do not want to add the config files to .gitignore.

Comment: This isn't really a good use for branches; staging isn't a separate development path from production, it's just code that hasn't made it to production *yet*. Typically you create a branch for each *version* of your application (e.g. 1.0, 1.1), and use it for fixing bugs found in testing. That way only the fixes have to be merged back.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having the settings as environment variables, I steer away from publishing my secret keys and other production settings to git.  Each environment can have their own distinct settings

Comment: they aren't secret keys, just the application ID and the name of the Google Bucket. Each environment has it's own bucket and I need the application ID in place when updating the app through the GAE PHP SDK.

Comment: Still, keeping these as env variables makes it easy for other team members to change the settings without the need to commit anything and  your servers will have the right info since its a server side setting.  I usually have good defaults in my config if the env variables are not set (typically dev settings since production should be more managed)

Comment: Ok, I've managed to pass the application id as an argument when launching instead of replying on the app.yaml file so I can leave that set to staging by default the only issue now is the php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a practical usage of git. What I would recommend doing is writing the file in a way that says something like:

```
IF 'Local' Then
  ...
ELSE IF 'Staging' Then
  ...
ELSE IF 'Production' Then
  ...
ELSE
  ...
END IF
```

Instead of having a separate file for each branch.

Comment: I can't do that with these particular configuration files.

Comment: Could you possibly write a build script instead?

Comment: I'm using Google App Engine. I'm unfamiliar with build scripts, not sure how I could utilize them...